# iOS binary search code crash above 256 items

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c, search, binary-search

I've used iOS default code to search string in custom dictionary object which exist in array, Means array of dictionary items.

```
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, artistThumbnail.count);
index = [artistThumbnail indexOfObject:artist
                         inSortedRange:searchRange
                               options:NSBinarySearchingLastEqual
                       usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
    NSString *artistName = (NSString *)obj2;
    NSDictionary *artistThumbnail = (NSDictionary *)obj1;
    NSString *artistToCompare = artistThumbnail[_artist_thumb];
    NSComparisonResult result = [artistToCompare compare:artistName];
    return result;
}];
```

When I used same code with less then equal to 256 objects code work fine no crash, both `Obj1` and `Obj2` have the dictionary object, but when array have >256 items then it crash and I've noticed that obj1 and obj2 not the same as the previously always come in `NSDictionary` format.

Comment: Any error message when it crashes?

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance..

Comment: Full error message? Because that’s a known error and it gives more usefull infos

Comment: [__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001cfaf00

Comment: It means that at one point obj2 was a NSString and not a NSDictionnary. Could you print the values and check when it fails?

Comment: I already spend many hours, when exactly there is >256 item in array(which came from server) it gives string in obj1 in 2nd loop always. but when under 256 items it never crash. I've many apps which run this code in and all are live.

Comment: From what I understand, at 256, the items obj1 and obj2 can be inversed (and it's not necessary obj1 the dict, and obj2 the string). It would need a search on how it's implemented.

Comment: Another bug from apple :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your comparison object is of a different type than your array elements. If you type the array properly as `NSArray<NSDictionary *> *` you get a warning saying that parameter `indexOfObject` should be of type `NSDictionary *`.

Furthermore, you cannot rely on the `artist` object always is passed as `obj2` to the comparison function. The documentation does not say anything about this, so you should assume that it can be passed as `obj1` sometimes and `obj2` other times.

To solve it you can embed the `artist` in a dictionary to make it the same format as an array element like this `@{ _artist_thumb: artist }`. Then you retrieve the name from *both* parameters the same way.

```
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, artistThumbnail.count);
index = [artistThumbnail indexOfObject:@{ _artist_thumb: artist }
                                    inSortedRange:searchRange
                                          options:NSBinarySearchingLastEqual
                                  usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
    NSString *artistName = ((NSDictionary *)obj2)[_artist_thumb];
    NSDictionary *artistThumbnail = (NSDictionary *)obj1;
    NSString *artistToCompare = artistThumbnail[_artist_thumb];
    NSComparisonResult result = [artistToCompare compare:artistName];
    return result;
}];
```

Comment: Your code works, but I already updated my code with predicate, Thanks man, but my real question is not the solution, why above code is work for 256 element and not for above 256 element.

Comment: My guess is that the binary search is using different algorithms depending on the number of elements. Maybe it actually does a linear search for small sets? So, depending on exactly what it does, it will pass parameters differently. In any case you should keep the parameters consistent.

Comment: Another bug from apple